# Large Numerical difference in variance calculation : Unable to decipher

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance

For the below pdf, I've calculated variance by two methods and observe a large difference (2.1477 vs 2.9100). Wondering why is this difference right at the first decimal? Is it just loss of precision when we square a small difference in $E(X-E(X))^2$ compared to large squares in $EX^2$?

[image]

$$E(X)= 1\times 0.10 + 2\times 0.15 + .. = 3.3$$
$$Var(X)=E(X-E(X))^2 = (1-3.3)^2\times 0.10 + \\(2-3.3)^2\times 0.15 + .. = 2.1477$$

$$E(X^2)= 1^2\times 0.10 + 2^2\times 0.15 + .. = 13.8$$
$$Var(X)=E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 13.8 - (3.3)^2 = 2.9100$$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course, they won't because the PDF/PMF example violates the basic principle:
$$\sum_x P(X=x)=1$$
i.e. sum of all probabilities is not $1$. If, for example, you set $P(X=6)=0.17$, both variance calculations should match.